node server (express.js) can't make external API request after a while
(sorry for bad english) I have a web server in node.js (express.js), and in one route I make a external API request (POST), parse response, and send back as route response. It works ok for a while, but after 45-60 minutes of no calling that route, external API request won't respond, and got timeout error (try/catch)
Tried with many libs (axios, fetch, http), setting timeout in 10s, 20s, 30s, 60s and even tried to keep initial connection or create a new one without success. After restart node server (I use PM2), request to external API works wihtout problem for a while. What could be the problem?

Please add the relevant piece of code along with the error message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
